Insufficient Quota for High-End GPU Virtual Machine in Azure Machine Learning Studio with Azure for Students Account
I created an Azure account for students to create machine learning models. but when I want a workspace and compute instance in Azure Machine Learning studio, I have a problem with the virtual machine type when I select GPU, it doesn't give me the choice Standard_ND96amsr_A100_v4
96 cores, 1924 GB RAM, 2900 GB storage
8 x NVIDIA A100 It shows me that your quota is insufficient for the following virtual machine sizes. Click here to view and order a class. Why? thanks
i try to chose GPU without taille machine learning like nvidia but when run model in jupyter he fonctionne 9h..

Running machine learning models on a GPU can significantly reduce training time compared to running on a CPU. check your current quota limits and usage by following the instructions in the Azure portal. If you need more quota, you can request an increase by following the instructions provided in the Azure documentation.


Manage budgets, costs, and quota for Azure Machine Learning at organizational scale
How to deploy large language models with Azure AI Studio - Quota considerations


You’re facing an issue where your student account does not have sufficient quota to provision high-end GPU virtual machines such as the Standard_ND96amsr_A100_v4, which is one of the most powerful GPU instances available in Azure.
Why ?

Quota Limits: Azure imposes quota limits to manage resources on their platform effectively. For student accounts, these limits are
typically lower to minimize the risk of running up large bills.

Cost Control: High-end GPUs like the NVIDIA A100 are expensive resources. Limiting access to these resources on student accounts
helps prevent unexpected high charges.

Resource Availability: High-end GPUs are in high demand and limited supply. Azure might restrict access to ensure broader
availability for enterprise and research customers who have higher
priority based on their business needs.


Workaround?
You can request a quota increase, although approval might depend on your account type and intended use:

Navigate to the Subscriptions section of your Azure portal.
Select the subscription you are using for Azure Machine Learning.
Under Settings, choose Usage + quotas.
Locate and select the type of resource for which you need an increase (GPUs in this case).
Click on Request increase and fill out the form. You will need to justify why you need more resources.


However, for Students accounts, the likelihood of getting approval for high-end GPUs like the A100 series might be low without a compelling educational or research need. But give it a shot.
If increasing the quota is not feasible, you can opt for lower-spec GPU models that are more likely to be approved under student quotas, such as the K80, V100, or P100 GPUs or check the different VM sizes that are available and try
Since running your model takes a long time even on lesser GPUs you can optimize your code to ensure it runs efficiently. Look into model simplification, batch size adjustments, and other GPU acceleration techniques.
Reference-

Manage budgets, costs, and quota for Azure Machine Learning at organizational scale
How to deploy large language models with Azure AI Studio - Quota considerations


Did you create this answer with ChatGPT?

Not sure why is my answer flagging. Answer has 0% ChatGPT content
